# Display Alert when push arrives

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

How Can I Display an alert when push notification arrives from C2DM or GCM. Right now I am displaying notifications on status bar. So How can I get a notification as an alert.

Comment: What do you consider an "alert" to be? Bear in mind that users like `Notifications` to let them know about things in the background, unless the event is really really important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Popping a dialog in the middle of something a user is doing is a wildly user hostile thing to do. What if they're playing Angry Birds and you've just ruined their shot? Only the platform can and should get away with that.

Use the notification area, like Google intended, UNLESS you app currently has control (your activity is in running state). Then just use that activity's context to pop an `AlertDialog()`. You can detect if the activity is running by overriding `onResume()` and `onPause()` - anything that happens in between is your activity's time.

An AlertDialog can be popped like this:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(Ctxt) //Use an activity object here
    .setMessage(R.string.MyMessageID) //Provide a message here... A string or a string ID will do
    .setCancelable(true) //If you want them to be able to dismiss with a Back button
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.IDS_NO, null) //No action on NO, right?
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.IDS_YES, OnYesClickListener) //Plug your own listener...
    .create()
    .show();
```

For a simple message/Yes/No dialog, an `AlertDialog` would suffice. For more complicated UI, derive a class from `Dialog` and design your own layout.

Comment: How to get that 'Ctxt' activity object inside IntentService?

Comment: `IntentService` derives from Context. Use `this`.

Comment: However, using intent service as context doesn't work here. Error: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: If there's an active activity, use that activity. If there isn't, see my answer.

Comment: And one more thing run the code in UI thread by calling the function activity.runOnUiThread()

Answer (score 1):

For Alert you need to write code in

generateNotification(Context context, String message)

in this method.

Thanks

Comment: can u explain more coz  i am a new on push notification. Please expand your answer .

Comment: if you any push notification then GCMBaseIntentService on onMessage method notify that one message receive via push notification then call the generateNotification method to generate Notification and show it android status bar...I think it help you.

Comment: I want to notify the user that a push is arrived when some app is in foreground. I want to do this using alert Dialog box with YES or NO options.